# Why does the binomial theorem for negative numbers never terminate

Tags: binomial-theorem

Why does $(a+bx)^n$ never terminate if you use negative numbers or fractions for n?

Surely $(a+bx)^{-2}=\frac{1}{a^2+2abx+b^2x^2}$ and not an infinite series?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know that $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n\geqslant 0} x^n$ ?

Comment: But your fraction, although right, is not a sum of powers of $x$ times coefficients.

Comment: ok I'm confused

Comment: All I want to know is why the fraction is not equal to the expansion?

Comment: @Think they are equal; they are two different ways of expressing equal things, like 1/3 = .3333333...

Comment: If the series terminated then you would have a polynomial in $x$.  Repeatedly differentiating that enough times will eventually give you $0$.  So does differentiating $(a+bx)^n$ (think chain rule).  But differentiating $(a+bx)^{-2}$ will never give you zero no matter how many times you do it, so it cannot be expressed by a polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n$ is real, there exist coefficients $a_{k}$ such that
$$
(1 + x)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} x^{k}
$$
for all real $x$ in some interval about $0$. (In fact, there is a [formula for $a_{k}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem), but that's incidental to the question.) The main points are:

- If $n$ is a non-negative integer, only finitely many $a_{k}$ are non-zero.
- If $n$ is not a non-negative integer, infinitely many $a_{k}$ are non-zero. (Compare Captain Lama's and Erick Wong's comments.)
- While it's true that
  $$
  \frac{1}{(1 + x)^{2}} = \frac{1}{1 + 2x + x^{2}},\quad x \neq -1,
  $$
  the right-hand side is not a power series (though it can be *written as* a power series, compare hunter's and coffeemath's comments.)